# woocommerce shipping depending of items in cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, woothemes

All my items have variation for shipping day. Tuesday or Friday:

[image: example]

I want to charge extra for shipping if the user has in the cart items for Tuesday and Friday. Not sure how I can get all items in cart, then check variation and modify the shipping charge.

```
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart(  ) {
global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        if ( sizeof( $items ) >= 1 ) {
            foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
                $_product = $values['data'];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$_product ');</script>";
            }           
        } 
};

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
```

I've gotten this far. Inside the `if`, I want to print the product array just to see how the value of product variation is called.   But is not working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work this way

```
function get_variation_data_from_variation_id( $item_id ) {
    $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $item_id );
    $variation_data = $_product->get_variation_attributes();
    $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, true );  // this will give all variation detail in one line
    // $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, false);  // this will give all variation detail one by one
    return $variation_detail; // $variation_detail will return string containing variation detail which can be used to print on website
    // return $variation_data; // $variation_data will return only the data which can be used to store variation data
}


// define the woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link callback 
function wc_ninja_change_flat_rates_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    if (WC()->cart->cart_contents_count > 1) {
        $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        $first_item = array_shift($cart_items);
        $variation1 = get_variation_data_from_variation_id($first_item['data']->variation_id);
        foreach(  $cart_items as $cart_item ) { 
            $variations =   get_variation_data_from_variation_id($cart_item['data']->variation_id); 
             if( $variations  != $variation1 ){
                $rates['flat_rate:5']->cost = 20;
                break;
             }//end if
        } //end for
    } //end if
debug_to_console($rates);
    return $rates;
};

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'wc_ninja_change_flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```